# classic asp request form and variables

Tags: forms, variables, asp-classic, request.form

I need some help here. I got this simple username/password script to enable a login page. It is basically a form asking a username/password and comparing with some info inside the code.

```
If Request.Form("FormUsername") = "username" AND Request.Form("FormPassword") = "password" Then
```

What I would like to do is compare user/pass info from some variable, like having a second file with the variables:

```
<%
'Username Variables
Dim PCUser, PCPass

PCUser = "username"
PCPass = "password"
%>
```

then include the file to the login page:

```
<!--#include file="Users.inc"-->
```

And then be able to read the variables on the request.form:

```
If Request.Form("FormUsername") = "& PCUser &" AND Request.Form("FormPassword") = "& PCPass &" Then
```

That's what I tried so far and didn't work :(
Could anyone help me figure out why???

If I do a response.write at the end of the page it will show me the variables values:

```
<%
Response.Write("user= " & PCUser & "<br />")
Response.Write("pass= " & PCPass & "<br />")
%>
```

thanks in advance

PC

Comment: `"& PCUser &"` should be just `PCUser`. And what does your HTML form look like?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
If Request.Form("FormUsername") = PCUser 
      AND Request.Form("FormPassword") = PCPass Then
```

2nd try:

```
response.write "FormUsername: " & Request.Form("FormUsername")
response.write "PCUser: " & PCUser
response.write "Equals: " & (Request.Form("FormUsername") = PCUser)
```

Check using the above in both the main page and the include file.

Comment: nothing :(

for the records I am putting the include before the if request.form, so it should be able to read the variables just like the code I have at the end of the page, right???

Comment: I put your suggestion at the end of my page and I got this response: FormUsername: usernamePCUser: usernameEquals: True  BUT if I put right before the If Request.form it will give me a false statement: FormUsername: usernamePCUser: Equals: False

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach might be to put the username and password in an application variable, in the global.asa in the root of your site:

```
<script language=vbscript runat=server>
    SUB Application_OnStart
            Application.contents("username") = "username"
            Application.contents("password") = "password" 
    END SUB
</script>
```

That makes your username and password available in the entire application. In your pages you can check it like so (without needing an include):

```
If Request.Form("FormUsername") = Application.contents("username") AND Request.Form("FormPassword") = Application.contents("password") Then
    ...
End if
```

Ofcourse, the way to proceed from there would be to make a login page, and as soon as the user has logged in with the correct username and password, set a session variable (which is per-user), and just check the session variable to see if someone is logged in:

GLOBAL.ASA:

```
<script language=vbscript runat=server>
    ' run when the application is started for the first time or re-started
    SUB Application_OnStart
            Application.contents("username") = "username"
            Application.contents("password") = "password" 
    END SUB

    ' run for each user when he or she first visits the site
    SUB Session_OnStart 
            Session.Contents("loggedIn") = False
    END SUB
</script>
```

Your login page can set the session to TRUE when a user logs in successfully:

```
If Request.Form("FormUsername") = Application.contents("username") AND Request.Form("FormPassword") = Application.contents("password") Then
    Session("loggedIn") = True
End if
```

At the top of every page you want to secure, you can then do this:

```
If NOT Session("loggedIn") Then 
    Response.redirect("/login.asp")    ' redirect to your login page
End If
```

This last piece of code can be placed in an include file and added to the top of all pages you'd like to secure.

Please note that this is a very rudimental security system and the code is untested.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. What am I trying to achieve here is to figureout why it wont work with variables. If I write the username and password directly on the request.fprm it will work, but I would like to use variables because that will make changes/updates to the username/password easier to someone who dont know about asp and programing. At this point it will have just one user.
<br><br>
about the end of your code, about the cookie session, I already doing that :)